# Why the Conditional Color Styling inside the Reactable is not working?

Tags: r, dt, flextable, gt, reactable

#### Data

```
df <- tibble(
  x = rep(paste0( "del", 1:10 ), 100),
  y = rep(paste0( "topic", 1:5 ), 200),
  z = paste0("question", 1:1000),
  w = 1:1000
)
```

#### Code

```
reactable(
  df,
  groupBy = c("x", "y"),
  columns = list(
    w = colDef(
      aggregate = "mean",
      style = JS(
        "function(rowInfo) {
        var value = rowInfo.row.extra
        if (value > 500) {
          var color = '#008000'
        } else {
          var color = '#e00000'
        }
        return { color: color, fontFamily: 'monospace' }
      }")
    )
  )
)
```

#### Question

For some reason, the JS code `if (value > 500)` is not evaluating to TRUE when the value is indeed bigger than 500.
Am i missing something?
Why is that and how do i fix?

Answer (score 0):

In using datatables (presumably using a similar javascript call) I used this snippet wrapped in JS()

```
"
 value <= 10 ? 'green' : (value <= 15 ? 'yellow' : (value >= 15 ? 'red' : 'white'))
"
```

If a value is less than 10 its green, between 10 and 15 its yellow and greater than 15 its red.

Could a similar syntax be what you need?

```
"
value>500 ? '#008000' : 'e00000'
"
```